# until/since + adverb

Tags: sentence-construction

I know we can say ***A year ago***, ***Three years ago*** as an adverb.

But can I say like

> 1. ***Until 3 years ago***, I lived my whole life doing what I don't want to do.
> 2. ***Ever since a year ago***, I've live my life doing what I want to do.

Why I'm asking this is because I'm not comfortable saying **until/since + adverb**.

So. do the sentences above sound natural?

Comment: Three years ago, I lived my life doing what I don't want to do.  UntlE I met her three years ago, I lived......

Comment: Related: [Is “last two years ago, I was in a classical concert” correct?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104040/is-last-two-years-ago-i-was-in-a-classical-concert-a-correct-sentence) The answers are very helpful.

Comment: 1st sentence: "don't" is awkward (inconsistent tense).  "didn't" would be better.  2nd sentence: "ever" is used when there is not a reference to a specific time period ("ever since X happened".  "Since a year ago" would be correct, or "For the last year" would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence sounds like natural English. Using "Ever since a year ago" in your second sentence does not sound natural.  I would suggest the following for your second sentence:

> **For a year now**, I've **lived** my life doing what I want to do.

(The bolded words signify what I changed from your original sentence.)

Now, my answer above assumes you are not writing the two sentences one after another.  If you are, I would recommend something like...

> For my entire career, I lived my life doing what I don't want to do.  A year ago, I made a change.  Now, I live my life doing what *I* want to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using `Ever since a year ago`.  You can say things like `Ever since I lost my tooth` and it's no different.

Comment: @dockeryZ, "ever" would be used to refer to an event without a specific date: "ever since I lost my tooth".  If the reference contains a date, you wouldn't use "ever": "since a year ago".

Comment: "Since" can be paired with either a noun phrase representing an event ("Since Christmas") or with a verb phrase ("Since I lost my tooth"), but it would be odder with a phrase containing "ago". That said, I could see it in exchanges like: "You're a vegetarian? Since when?" — "Since a year ago!"