# Is "last two years ago, I was in a classical concert " a correct sentence?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases

In my English class my Teacher said I cannot use "Last two years ago...", so what should I use correctly?

Comment: Perhaps, "last two years" or "two years ago".

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to say. Are you talking about a single event that happened in 2014 or some ongoing activity that started in 2014.

Comment: Yes... "Last two years ago, I was in a classical concert "that was the sentence i had said. @djna

Comment: Two years ago I attended a classical concert.  That's a single event. If instead you had been learning to play an instrument: For the last two years I have been learning to play the violin.

Answer (score 8):

**Last two years ago* is incorrect because it combines two constructions with different senses:

- *Ago* is a preposition which, unusually, follows its object. That object is a measurement of distance in time and designates a **time point** (though it may be a rather fuzzy point) at that distance in the past. It's used to designate the date or time **at** which an eventuality occurred:

  > ***Two years ago*** I answered a question about stative verbs. *—that is, I answered the question in September of 2014. (It was actually on [September 15](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33552/32), but as I said, the 'point' is fairly fuzzy.)*
- *The last* (not bare *last*) are a determiner and an adjective<sup>†</sup>; when this group is attached to a nominal which designates a measurement of distance in time it designates a **timespan** of that length reaching from the past right up to the present. The entire noun phrase is used with a preposition such as *in* or *for* or *since* to designate the period **during** which one or more eventualities occurred:

  > ***In the last two years*** I have answered thirteen questions tagged [perfect-constructions](/questions/tagged/perfect-constructions). *—that is, during the period running from September, 2014 up to the present I answered thirteen questions.*

  Note that the noun phrase *the last [<sub><sup>TIME MEASUREMENT</sup></sub>]* can also be used without a preposition to designate the period itself:

  > **The last two years** have gone by very quickly.

Combining *last* and *ago*, your phrase tries to characterize *two years* simultaneously as both a time point and a time span. You have to pick one or the other.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>As Ahmad suggests, it is arguable that last* in temporal contexts should be considered a determinative, and *the last* a Determiner Phrase*—but that doesn't affect the point at issue here.</sub>

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that "last" and "ago" are not used in the same noun phrase. Unless in sentences like: *The last time I saw a ballet was two years ago.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA Quite so; I've added remarks explaining that.

Comment: @StoneyB I polished my answer. It seems we can't use "the last two years" without a preposition unless it is the subject or object of the sentence. right?

Comment: For my last example, can we say "the last two years **was** difficult for my family? maybe not but "the last two years before my acceptance to the university **was** a difficult time for me"

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, that is idiomatic: a timespan like that may be treated as a plural quantity of units (years, weeks, days, hours, &c) OR a singular block of time.

Answer (score 4):

"ago" is used to specify **a time point** in the past when something happened. Before "ago" you need a **time period** like "two years" or "10 minutes" to specify how long ago it happend:

> 5 minutes ago
>
> an hour ago
>
> a long time ago
>
> some time ago
>
> two years ago

bare "last" without "the" is used as a determiner (opposite of **next**) to specify a time.

> last year, last night, last week

*last* can also be used as an **adjective** to point to something that is at the end in a sequence.

> the last person
>
> the last chapter of the book
>
> the last two years
>
> the last year

Note, when you point to **the last two years**, you point to a specific time period ("two years") which is the last one. It spans from two years ago to the present and you usually use a "present perfect" tense with it

> I have been learning English in the last two years.

This time period can also be used as the subject or object of the sentence.

> The last two years have been very difficult for my family.